# Improving Deployed Server Performance of Large File Uploads

Tags: node.js, performance, express, file-upload, server

I’m currently working on a web application that deals with large file uploads (we’re talking 100mb to up to a gigabyte), and then reading that file into memory. I’m attempting to host the server on Heroku, but even with upgraded levels, the server struggles in 1) EXTREMELY slow upload speed - will take like 20-30 minutes for a decently sized file, and 2) memory issues when reading the file into memory. How would you go about improving performance in this scenario? Is the main concern RAM?

The stack we’re using is React in the front end, Node/Express for the back end.

Also worth noting, we’re currently looking to host our own server via our own Linux PC. This PC will obviously have more RAM and power than a Heroku server - will this actually improve performance when it comes to file uploads?

We're tried so far:

- Compressing the file in the front-end, but it causes Chrome to crash
- Upgrading Heroku to pro levels

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code with your upload logic

Comment: @JanithKasun it's simply just the frontend sending the file in the body, and the server receiving it via middleware. Let me know if theres anything specific i should post?

Comment: Are you using a express server as your back end, can you post the relevant route and the middle ware if it is